# How to iterate through a tuple2 containing lists in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a function that returns a tuple2 object from the method splitAt.How to get individual objects(2 lists) from the tuple2?
Here is my function

```scala
def isPalindrome(x:List[Int])={
   val long=x.length
   if (long%2==0){
      println("Liste paire")
   }
   else{
      x.splitAt((long/2).toInt)
   }
}
val spl=isPalindrome(List(1,2,3,4,6))
spl
```

```
res128: Any = (List(1, 2),List(3, 4, 6))
```

```scala
println(spl(1))
```

```
<console>:13: error: Any does not take parameters
```

Update: I tried spl._1

```scala
println(spl._1)
```

```
<console>:13: error: value _1 is not a member of Any
```

Comment: ```spl._1``` and ```spl._2```

Comment: What do you want your `isPalindrome` to return if `long%2==0`?

Comment: @FedericoPellegatta My function wasn't complete then. First, I wanted to split the list into two, reverse the second part and check if the two are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that your function not always returns a list, a number or an object. The result depends if the list.length is even or odd pair.

If possibile, for sake of simplicity, from a function I would always expect the same type.

For example a function named `isPalindrome` suggest that returns a `Boolean`.

```scala
def isPalindrome(x:List[Int]):Boolean = {
  x.equals(x.reverse)
}
```

And once you found that your list is palindrome or not you can print your result.

```
if (isPalindrome(List(1,2,3,4,6))) {
   println("is Palindrome")
} else {
   println("not Palindrome")
}
```

Or split the list and print the results as you want.

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,6)
val t2 = x.splitAt(x.size/2)

println(t2._1)
println(t2._2)
```

Comment: What is the best practice then?

Comment: @djohon IMHO this answer is far better from the first I wrote.

Comment: ah yes you're right @freedev it's the simpliest solution. i didn't think about it that way. Anyway the answers helped me learn some tricks about the language.

Answer (score 0):

Scala can not determine if spl is a tuple or Unit , so its type is erased to `Any`.
you can cast it to a tuple:

```
 spl.asInstanceOf[(List[Int],List[Int])]
```

or use match:

```
spl.match{
    case s:(List[Int],List[Int])=>//Do something
    case _=>//Something else
```

Comment: seems like scala doesn't recognize match   `error:identifier expected but 'match' found`.

Comment: sorry,it's a typo. spl match{   there is no dot here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will solve your problem at all but the functionality what you want can be achieved like below :

```
def isPalindrome(x:List[Int])={
  val long=x.length
  if (long%2==0){
    println("Liste paire")
  }
  else{
    x.splitAt((long/2).toInt)
  }
}
val spl:Any=isPalindrome(List(1,2,3,4,6))
val splMatched = spl match {
  case (a , b) => (a, b)
  case _ => (Nil,Nil)
}
println(splMatched._1)
```

Comment: Thanks @FaigB it is what i was expecting. But what is the purpose of the second case? `case _ => (Nil,Nil)` ? I know Nil means Null or Nothing

Comment: In case of not expected data when spl not matches tuple2 pattern and you need just tuple2 in rest of your implementation. So it will prevent any broke downs :)

Comment: However i have a warning `<console>:13: warning non-variable type argument List[Int] in type pattern (List[Int],List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` `case x:(List[Int],List[Int]) => x`

Comment: As you get spl with type Any it can be anything and for your purpose you need tuple2, in case of correct data it can be achieved but if the data not fit first case then mapped with (Nil,Nil).

Comment: Edited code snippet which is without warning and fits with Any :)